# Change variable value when passing as argument (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, variables

is there a way i can do like this in vb.net

```
dim idx = -1
dim a = array(idx = idx + 1)
dim b = array(idx = idx + 1)
dim c = array(idx = idx + 1)
dim d = array(idx = idx + 1)
```

what i want is that idx keeps incrementing after each line, without incrementing it on a seperate line.

Thank you

Comment: You can use `++idx` to add 1 to it before, e.g. `dim a = array(++idx)`

Comment: See this [Article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/preincrement)

Comment: I don't think VB.net supports ++

Comment: +=1 would be the VB equivalent to ++

Comment: dim a = array(idx += 1) gives syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think VB.Net has anything like that, but you can make an extension to get close to it:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Module1

  <Extension()> _
  Public Function UpIndex(ByRef value As Integer) As Integer
    value += 1
    return value
  End Function

End Module
```

Note the use of `ByRef` in the arguments.

Then your call would look like this:

```
Dim a = array(idx.UpIndex)
Dim b = array(idx.UpIndex)
```

Comment: great idea. clean code :) except it should be return value (byref)